# Is Titanium support ARC?

Tags: titanium, automatic-ref-counting, titanium-mobile

Is titanium iPhone apps support ARC (Automatic reference counting) ? How can i create project with ARC support in Titanium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can say that Titanium Mobile SDK source code does not use ARC. So the project you created with Titanium will not support ARC too. Also you can't directly use compiler features in your Titanium project. You have to hack SDK builder scripts to pass compiler options.

Comment: Is it possible to build an iOS Titanium module that uses ARC and use it in a Titanium app?

Comment: Now, yes. With version 3.0.2GA modules uses ARC are supported.

Issue TIMOB-12558: Allow external modules to use ARC.